# Eigenvalues-Eigenvectors and Rotation (in $\mathbb{R^2}$)

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

- Let $A$ be a matrix. If there is a vector $\overrightarrow {0}\neq \overrightarrow {x}$ such that

$A\overrightarrow {x}=\lambda\overrightarrow {x}$

for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, then $\overrightarrow {x}$ is called eigenvector of $A$ with to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

*Example*. Consider $R_\theta$, $\theta\neq 0$ and let $\overrightarrow {v}\neq \overrightarrow {0}$. Then, note that $R_\theta (\overrightarrow {v})\neq \overrightarrow {v}$. So $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $R_\theta$.

**My question is:** Why $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $R_\theta$., why $R_\theta (\overrightarrow {v})\neq \overrightarrow {v}$? I couldn't understand these, can you help?

**My question is in $\mathbb{R^2}$**.

Comment: It's not strictly true. If $\theta = 2\pi$ then $R_{\theta}$ is the identity matrix, so $1$ is an eigenvalue. But if we constrain $0 < \theta < 2\pi$ then it's true. This is because $R_{\theta} x$ is the rotation of $x$ by $\theta$, which can't be the same as $x$ unless $x=0$.

Comment: If $A \overrightarrow x \neq \overrightarrow x$ for all $\overrightarrow x \neq \overrightarrow 0$, then there cannot be any $\overrightarrow x$ such that satisfies $A \overrightarrow x = \lambda \overrightarrow x$ for $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: @AdamFrancey Edited question.

Comment: @Bungo Edited question.

Comment: @Kahler Find the explicit definition of $R_{\theta}$ and multiply it by an anonymous vector $\overrightarrow x = (x_1,x_2)$. What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

For a 3d rotation matrix $R_\theta$, $1$ is an eigenvalue with an eigenvector pointing along the axis of rotation. For a 2d rotation matrix, there are no real eigenvalues/eigenvectors.

Comment: Edited question.

Answer (score 0):

**Claim:** If $\overrightarrow{v} =
\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1 \\
    v_2
\end{bmatrix}
$
 is an eigenvector of $R_\theta$ with eigenvalue 1, then $\overrightarrow{v} = \overrightarrow{0}$.

**Proof:**

By definition, the rotation matrix in two dimensions is

$$R_\theta = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta)       & -\sin(\theta) \\
    \sin(\theta)       & \cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and so

$$R_\theta \overrightarrow {v} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    v_1\cos(\theta) - v_2\sin(\theta)\\
    v_1\sin(\theta) +  v_2\cos(\theta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If $\overrightarrow {v}$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1, then $R_\theta \overrightarrow {v} = \overrightarrow {v}$. In other words, we have the system of equations:

$$v_1\cos(\theta) - v_2\sin(\theta) = v_1 \quad (1)\\
  v_1\sin(\theta) +  v_2\cos(\theta) = v_2 \quad (2)
$$

We now solve for $v_1$ and $v_2$.

Rearranging equation (1),
$$v_1 = \frac{v_2\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta) - 1}$$

Substitute this into equation (2),
$$\frac{v_2\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta) - 1}\sin(\theta) +  v_2\cos(\theta) = v_2 $$

Or,

$$v_2(\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\cos(\theta) - 1}\sin(\theta) +  \cos(\theta) - 1) = 0 $$

Since this equation has to hold for all $\theta$, this tells us that $v_2 = 0$.

Substituting $v_2 = 0$ into equation 2,

$$v_1\sin(\theta) = 0$$

Again, this must hold for all $\theta$ so $v_1 = 0$.

Therefore, $\overrightarrow{v} = \begin{bmatrix}
    v_1 \\
    v_2
\end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    0
\end{bmatrix}
= \overrightarrow{0}
$.

By contraposition, if an eigenvector $\overrightarrow{v} \neq \overrightarrow{0}$ then its eigenvalue is not 1.